# How to interact with social websites (auto youtube posting, finding titles of new videos etc.) from the command line

Tags: javascript, python, bash, youtube, command-line-interface

I would like to write a script to access data on a website, such as:

1) automatically searching a youtuber's profile for a new posting, and printing the title of it to stdout.

2) automatically posting a new video, question, or comment to a website at a specified time. For a lot of sites, there is a required login, so that is something that would need to be automated as well.

I would like to able to do all this stuff from the command line.

What set of tools should I use for this? I was intending to use Bash, mostly because I am in the process of learning it, but if there are other options, like Python or Javascript, please let me know.

In a more general sense, it would be nice to know how to read and directly interact with a website's JS; I've tried looking at the browser console, but I can't make much sense of it.

Answer (score 1):

Python or Node (JS) will probably be a lot easier for this task than Bash, primarily because you're going to have to do OAuth to get access to the social network.

Or, if you're willing to get a bit "hacky", you could issue scripts to PhantomJS, and automate the interaction with the sites in question...

Comment: I would have thought PhantomJS was the less "hacky" of the two options, because it doesn't involve coding from scratch. Is PhatomJS operated from the command line?

Comment: Yes, PhantomJS is operated from the command line. If you're on bash, you can even use the shebang in your script to point to phantom and then just mark your script as executable.

The reason I consider PhantomJS the more "hacky" approach is that you'd be doing something akin to screen scraping, and you'd have to check for page loads and race conditions and such... and if the developers at any of these sites choose to change the IDs on the elements you're using to post, it will break your script and you'll have to update.